# Full Justify the contents of a Wrap Panel?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wrappanel

If you put this into Kaxaml:

```
<WrapPanel Width="500"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
  <Button Width="110"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="130"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="70"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="50"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="329"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="126"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="86"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="48"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="200"
          Height="100"></Button>
  <Button Width="190"
          Height="100"></Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

You see a bunch of buttons aligned with a ragged right side (but a justified left side).

**Is there a way to get the contents of each "row" to proportionally expand to fill that row?**  (So it will have straight lines on both right and left?)

Answer (score 2):

Not with the `WrapPanel` itself as what you're seeing it do is exactly what it is designed for. You could certainly write your own `Panel` to do just that but I think `TabPanel` (the default used for laying out `TabControl` tabs) does what you're trying to get.

Comment: This is perfect!  I had no idea there was a TabPanel; it does eactly what the original question asked.